# Using the right python package to achieve result

Tags: python, csv, xlsxwriter

I have a fixed width text file that I must convert to a .csv where all numbers have to be converted to integers (no commas, dollar signs, quotes, etc).  I have currently parsed the text file using plain python, but when utilizing the right package I seem to be at an impasse.

With csv, I can use writer.writerows in place of my print statement to write the output into my csv file, but the problem is that I have more columns (such as the date and time) that I must add after these rows that I cannot seem to do with csv.  I also cannot seem to find a way to translate the blank columns in my text document to blank columns in output. csv seems to write in order.

I was reading the documentation on xlsxwriter and I see how you can write to individual columns with a set formatting, but I am unsure if it would work with my .csv requirement

My input text has a series of random groupings throughout the 50k line document but follows the below format

```
     * START ******************************************************************************************************************** START *
 * START ******************************************************************************************************************** START *
 * START ******************************************************************************************************************** START *
1--------------------
1ANTECR09                                                 CHEK                                                 DPCK_R_009
                                                     TRANSIT EXTRACT SUB-SYSTEM
    CURRENT DATE = 08/03/2017                             JOURNAL     REPORT                                              PAGE    1
    PROCESS DATE =
 ID = 022000046-MNT                                                                      
    FILE HEADER = H080320171115                                      
+____________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________
     R               T      SEQUENCE    CR      BT                A RSN               ITEM           ITEM CHN          USER    REASO
        NBR       NBR       OR PIC NBR  DB      NBR              NBR COD             AMOUNT         SERIAL IND  .......FIELD..  DESCR
      5,556        01        7450282689 C 538196640        9835177743 15          $9,064.81              00                    CREDIT
      5,557        01        7450282690 D 031301422         362313705 38            $592.35           43431                    DR CR
      5,558        01        7450282691 D 021309379         601298839 38          $1,491.04           44896                    DR CR
      5,559        01        7450282692 D 071108834            176885 38          $6,688.00            1454                    DR CR
      5,560        01        7450282693 D 031309123     1390001566241 38            $293.42            6878                    DR CR
```

My code currently parses this document, pulls the date, time, and prints only the lines where the sequence number starts with 42 and the CR is "C"

```
lines = []
a = 'PRINT DATE:'
b = 'ARCHIVE'
c = 'PRINT TIME:'

with open(r'textfile.txt') as in_file:
    for line in in_file:
        values = line.split()
        if 'PRINT DATE:' in line:
            dtevalue = line.split(a,1)[-1].split(b)[0]
            lines.append(dtevalue)

        elif 'PRINT TIME:' in line:
            timevalue = line.split(c,1)[-1].split(b)[0]
            lines.append(timevalue)   

        elif (len(values) >= 4 and values[3] == 'C'
            and len(values[2]) >= 2 and values[2][:2] == '41'):
            print(line)



print (lines[0])
print (lines[1])
```

What would be the cleanest way to achieve this result, and am I headed in the right direction by writing out the parsing first or should I have just done everything within a package first?
Any help is appreciated

Edit:
the header block (between 1----------, and +___________) is repeated throughout the document, as well as different sized groupings separated by -------

```
 --------------------
     34,615       207        4100223726 C 538196620        9866597322 10            $645.49              00                    CREDIT
     34,616       207        4100223727 D 022000046        8891636675 31            $645.49          111583                    DR ON-
 --------------------
     34,617       208        4100223728 C 538196620          11701364 10            $756.19              00                    CREDIT
     34,618       208        4100223729 D 071923828                00 54            $305.31        11384597                    BAD AC
     34,619       208        4100223730 D 071923828          35110011 30            $450.88        10913052 6                  DR SEL
 --------------------
```

Comment: I haven't really looked into this, but keep in mind that, as a general rule, packages are there to help you with common problems, if you find that some package makes it more complicated - or even impossible - to tackle your task, then using your custom logic is perfectly fine.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend slicing fixed width blocks to parse through the fixed width fields. Something like the following (incomplete) code:

```
data = """      5,556        01        4250282689 C 538196640        9835177743 15          $9,064.81              00
          CREDIT
      5,557        01        7450282690 D 031301422         362313705 38            $592.35           43431
DR CR
      5,558        01        7450282691 D 021309379         601298839 38          $1,491.04           44896
DR CR
"""

# list of data layout tuples (start_index, stop_index, field name)
# TODO add missing data layout tuples
data_layout = [(0, 12, 'r_nbr'), (12, 22, 't_nbr'), (22, 39, 'seq'), (39, 42, 'cr_db')]

for line in data.splitlines():
    # skip "separator" lines
    # NOTE this may be an iterative process to identify these
    if line.startswith('-----'):
        continue
    record = {}
    for start_index, stop_index, name in data_layout:
        record[name] = line[start_index:stop_index].strip()

    # your conditional (seems inconsistent with text)
    if record['seq'].startswith('42') and record['cr_db'] == 'C':
        # perform any special handling for each column
        record['r_nbr'] = record['r_nbr'].replace(',', '')
        # TODO other special handling (like $)

        print('{r_nbr},{t_nbr},{seq},{cr_db},...'.format(**record))
```

Output is:

```
5556,01,4250282689,C,...
```

#### Update based on seemingly spurious values in undefined columns

Based on the new information provided about the "spurious" columns/fields (appear only rarely), this will likely be an iterative process.

My recommendation would be to narrow (appropriately!) the width of the desired fields. For example, if spurious data is in `line[12:14]` above, you could change the tuple for `(12, 22, 't_nbr')` to `(14, 22, 't_nbr')` to "skip" the spurious field.

An alternative is to add a "garbage" field in the list of tuples to handle those types of lines. Wherever the "spurious" fields appear, the "garbage" field would simply consume it.

If you *need* these fields, the same general approach to the "garbage" field approach still applies, but you save the data.

#### Update based on random separators

If they are relatively consistent, I'd simply add some logic (as I did above) to "detect" the separators and skip over them.

Comment: the text file i submitted is only a part of the entire thing.  I believe I stated above that it was about ~50k lines long.  The numbers change and there are random character separators between groupings, which is why I originally used py logic to search the whole file.  Instead of tuples, would there be a way to parse the entire document?

Comment: @mcclayjr01 Can you post a few example lines of the "random character separators"? If the fixed width layout is truly random, you might try building a more robust field detection capability, but based on the headers above, that looks fairly difficult. Incidentally, random separators may adversely impact some of the third-party "text table" reading packages, too, but they might prove useful here. I've not tried them personally so I won't offer a solution with those.

Comment: I added more examples.  I'm fairly new when it comes to python, so I've been mostly learning py logic.  I've been trying to read through documentation to find the best solutions and the final product may utilize more than one package, but I am having difficulties figuring out what packages work well together and how I can combine my previous py logic with the right package